# Problem with Atom and anaconda compatibility

Tags: python, macos, numpy

I am now learning numpy and therefore installed anaconda which comes with many python libraries. I used by now Atom with python.

Now I have problems with importing numpy. It seems as though both Atom and my Mac are using two different python versions

because when i am in the terminal and look up the version of python it gives me back this:

Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 08:50:36)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

However when I am in Atom and type in the terinal there it gives me back this:

Python 2.7.18

I tried to install numpy within Atom with the
"pip install numpy" call but it keeps giving me back that I have numpy already :

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.22.0)

I am just desperate and don't know how to make Atom run anaconda I tried several techniques described on stackoverflow with the shell override but nothing did work(with the ways I tried to do it), can anyone help me, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Mac, you need 2.7, but you don't want to run that version in Atom.

Install atom-runner into Atom, if not already installed. When installed (or if already installed), go to the package and click on view code.

[image]

[image]

From there, go to the project pane. In that pane, open the drop-down for the 'lib' folder and click on 'atom-runner.coffee'

[image]

Scroll to line 38 - is it python? Change it to 'python3'.

[image]

For the most part, you'll use 'python3' anywhere it says to use 'python' in a call in Terminal.